# Python argparse datetime

Tags: python, datetime, argparse

I would like to parse datetime from the command line:

python test.py -time 2017/2/9/ 10:30

But the argparse sees this as 2 seperate strings. I dont want to create another argparse argument just for time, is there a way to keep the date and time as 1 string?

Thanks

Comment: quote it. Also, that string is not well formatted to begin with.

Comment: With an underscore? Or just wrap the date and time in quotes? That's pretty much all you can do without adding an argument for time, which seems like the cleaner solution

Comment: Do I have to strip the quotes later?

Comment: @WeiZeng No, your shell should take care of that.

Comment: Thats really cool.... python is too smart for me. Thanks

Comment: Consider a format like: `'1970-01-01T16:40:00'` which joins date and time into one string.  Or any other single string format that your `strptime` can handle:  `datetime.datetime.strptime("21/11/06T16:30", "%d/%m/%yT%H:%M")`

Comment: `nargs=2` will let you enter two strings for this argument.  You could join them later when converting to a `datetime` object.